# Release public app for employees to Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

We are developing an app for a company and it should only be used by its employees. Releasing it privately through the Managed Play Store is not an option for us, and it would be preferable to not send the APK for download to the employees. Is it possible to release the app publicly to Google Play Store and force users to login with the company email? Or is this against the Play Store policies?